# I am creating a caesar cipher in Ruby but the caesar function never finishes

Tags: ruby, loops

Here is my code:

```
def caesar(string, shift_factor)
    alphabet = Array("a".."z")
    new_alph = alphabet.rotate(shift_factor)
    new_str = []
    new_str = string.downcase.split("")
    new_str.each do |i|
        print i
        if !alphabet.include?(i)
            new_str.push(i)
        else
            equals = alphabet.index(i)
            new_str.push(new_alph[equals])
        end
    end
end

caesar("What a string!", 0)

print new_str.join.capitalize!
```

The code just keeps on looping and I am not sure how to go about stopping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different variable for storing the result string.  How about this:

```
  def caesar(string, shift_factor)
      alphabet = Array("a".."z")
      new_alph = alphabet.rotate(shift_factor)
      new_str = string.downcase.split("")
      caesar_string = []
      new_str.each do |i|
        if !alphabet.include?(i)
          caesar_string.push(i)
        else
          equals = alphabet.index(i)
          caesar_string.push(new_alph[equals])
        end
      end
      caesar_string
  end

  caesar_string = caesar("What a string!", 0)

  print caesar_string.join.capitalize!
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: why do you write caesar_string after the two ends and before the final end?

Comment: Oh, in Ruby, the last line of a method is the implicit return statement.  I could be more explicit and have done `return ceasar_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `new_str` and in each iteration you're pushing another object onto the array so the loop will never end.

In your loop, if you instead replace the character at the index, then you should get the result you're looking for.

```
def caesar(string, shift_factor)
  alphabet = Array("a".."z")
  new_alph = alphabet.rotate(shift_factor)
  new_str = string.downcase.split("")

  new_str.each_with_index do |letter, i|
    if !alphabet.include?(letter)
      new_str[i] = letter
    else
      equals = alphabet.index(letter)
      new_str[i] = new_alph[equals]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. So do I have to add a new array and instead push i to that array?

Comment: Yeah, either use a new array or simply replace the character at the index of the current iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an example that in Ruby there is always more than one way of doing things:

```
def caesar(string, shift_factor)
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
  string.downcase.tr(alphabet.join, alphabet.rotate(shift_factor).join)
end
```

Comment: This does not account for uppercase letters like the example he provided.

Comment: @EricTerry whoops, missed that one. Updated the answer to reflect that.